# Куда делся блок Обсуждаемое на мете?

Tags: дефект, блок-важных-вопросов

Отображается только блок Важное на мете с единственной ссылкой.

Почему нет ещё трёх ссылок из блока Обсуждаемое на мете?

---

[image: Важное на мете с единственной ссылкой]

Comment: О, один вопрос появился.

Comment: Видимо, ничего не обсуждалось достаточно активно.